# Скорость вставки и удаления в ArrayList и LinkedList

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist, linked-list

Расскажите про скорость вставки и удаления, не очень понял что такое `константное время` и что за конструкции `O(1), O(n)`. 
Гуглил до этого нашел:

> Быстрый доступ к элементам по индексу за время O(1)
>   
>   Доступ к элементам по значению за линейное время O(n)

Что за быстрый доступ за время O(1) и что такое линейное время O(n) и как это всё измеряется/проверяется?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Константное время - имеется ввиду, что независимо от того, сколько будет элементов в структуре то при времени выполнения операции 1 секунду, это время останется как для 1000 элементов, так и для миллиона и для миллиарда и т.п.

Линейное время - означает, что чем больше элементов будет в структуре, тем дольше будет выполняться операция. Т.е. время будет множиться в зависимости от количества элементов `n*t`, где `t` время, а `n` количество элементов. Так например если в структуре 10 элементов и операция выполняется за 1 секунду, то для 100 элементов, она будет выполняться за 10 секунд, для 1000 элементов - 100 секунд.